# Программа выпадает с переполнением стека при заполнении TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, рекурсия, treeview

Пытаюсь заполнить TreeView, но программа стабильно выпадает с переполнением стека

структура стандартная Id, ParentID, Name

```
private void UpdateTreeView()
{
    trvMain.Nodes.Clear();
    var list = _datamanager.Department.GetList();
    var root = trvMain.Nodes.Add("Root");
    root.Tag = 0;
    BindTree(list, root);
    trvMain.ExpandAll();
}

public void BindTree(IEnumerable<Department> list, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    var nodes = list.Where(x => parentNode == null ? x.ParentId == 0 : x.ParentId == parentNode.Tag.ToInt());

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var _node = new TreeNode() { Name = "id" + node.Id.ToString(), Text = node.Name, Tag = node.ParentId };

        if (parentNode == null)
        {
            trvMain.Nodes.Add(_node);
        }
        else
        {
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(_node);
        }
        BindTree(list, _node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так, это что за язык? Java?

Comment: Ну явно не срабатывает условие выхода из рекурсии (`nodes` всегда не пустой). Нужно смотреть на примеры структуры `list`

Comment: _"`parentNode == null ? x.ParentId == 0 : x.ParentId == parentNode.Tag.ToInt()`"_ -- что делает это строка? первый `==`   понятно для чего, а для чего остальные `==`?

Comment: @RihardBrugekhaim ну, явно не java. Откуда в джаве var? Определенно с#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переполение стека происходит из-за того, что нет условия для прекращения рекурсии.
В следующем методе

```
void BindTree(IEnumerable<Department> list, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    var nodes = list.Where(...);
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        ...
        BindTree(list, _node);
    }
}
```

надо определить правильное условие в list.Where. В результате nodes при определенных условиях будет пустым, BindTree не вызовется и рекурсия прекратится.